# change the box of increment decrement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to make increment decrements box.

check here[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suman17018/5wkavhcd/1/)

i want the box like this[image]

i think need to change in html code

```js
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.add-to-cart .qty_pan").append('<div class="inc add">&#8250;</div><div class="dec add">&#8249;</div>');

    jQuery(".inputQty").on('click', '.add', function() {
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
  var newVal = 0;
    
        if (jQueryadd.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
       // AJAX save would go here
     } else {
       // Don't allow decrementing below zero
       if (oldValue > 1) {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
           // AJAX save would go here
       }
    if(oldValue == 1){
     newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
     }
     }
     jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });
 

});
```

```html
<div class="qty_pan">
        <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
</div>
```

please help me to edit this box with same functionality

Comment: Create those two button at two side, then add functionality to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is thing which you like to do.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#plus").click(function(){
      $("#qty").val( Number($("#qty").val()) + 1 );
    });
     $("#minus").click(function(){
      $("#qty").val( Number($("#qty").val()) - 1 );
    });
  });
```

```css
.btnplus{
    display:inline-block;
}

.qty_pan{
    display:inline-block;
}

.btnminus{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus" class="btnplus">+</button>
<div class="qty_pan">
        <input type="text" min="1" max="1000" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
</div>
<button id="minus" class="btnminus">-</button>
```

**And Changes/Updating** in your code is following:

```js
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.add-to-cart .qty_pan").append('<div class="inc add">&#8250;</div><div class="dec add">&#8249;</div>');

    jQuery("#plus, #minus").click(function(){
      
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
  var newVal = 0;
    
        if (jQueryadd.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
       // AJAX save would go here
     } else {
       // Don't allow decrementing below zero
       if (oldValue > 1) {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
           // AJAX save would go here
       }
    if(oldValue == 1){
     newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
     }
     }
     jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });
  
});
```

```css
.btnplus{
    display:inline-block;
}

.qty_pan{
    display:inline-block;
}

.btnminus{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus" class="btnplus">+</button>
<div class="qty_pan">
        <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
</div>
<button id="minus" class="btnminus">-</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#inc, #dec').on('click', function(){
  var val = +$('#qty').val();
  this.id === "inc" ? $('#qty').val(val+1) : $('#qty').val(val-1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qty_pan">
        <span id='dec'> - </span><input type="number" min="1" max="1000" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="" class="input-text qty" /><span id='inc'> + </span>
</div>
```